# WCF datetime format

Tags: ios, wcf, date-format

I developed WCF service that contains so many methods and these methods return json format. My main problem is when i have datacontract member has datetime type i get in json like this /Date(1233846970110-0500)/ which is causing me issue in IOS application. How can i write a global method that converts to MM/dd/yyyy format for very call. I tried to different methods but none works when i test it, always returns the same above format.

I tried in global.ascx like this but like

```
     private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        // Create Json.Net formatter serializing DateTime using the ISO 8601 format
        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

        var config = HttpHostConfiguration.Create().Configuration;
        config.OperationHandlerFactory.Formatters.Clear();
        config.OperationHandlerFactory.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonNetMediaTypeFormatter(serializerSettings));

        var httpServiceFactory = new HttpServiceHostFactory
        {
            OperationHandlerFactory = config.OperationHandlerFactory,
            MessageHandlerFactory = config.MessageHandlerFactory
        };

        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("VWPM_Srv", httpServiceFactory, typeof(IVWPM_Srv)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an MM/dd/yyyy formatted string. You just make the property a string and assign the date in the MM/dd/yyyy format.

However you can also make ios accept the dates wfc send you:

[json-serialized-date-passed-between-ios-and-wcf-and-vice-versa](http://zdravevski.com/blog/2012/05/27/json-serialized-date-passed-between-ios-and-wcf-and-vice-versa/)